# Can you reference a class name with a variable?

Tags: python, class, variables

I am making an RPG text based game with classes and subclasses. I'm importing other python files, each of which have their own classes. Each python file is the name of their RPG main class, each of which have multiple classes for the respective RPG subclass. My question is, if I wanted to access a variable from one of these classes from the main file (E.G. if I wanted to access the bard's spellist I'd do Bard.Bard.Spellist, (First bard being the file import, second being the name of the class), could I use a variable like:
x = input("Enter class from which to access the spellist: )
print(x.x.spellist)

hope that makes sense!

This is what I tried:

```
x = Bard

for item in x.x.SpellBook:
  print(item, ":", x.x.SpellBook[item])
```

I expected it to print a list of the names and spell level like this:
(spellname) : (spellevel)

It comes up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 82, in <module>
    for item in x.x.SpellBook:
AttributeError: module 'ClassFold.Bard' has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: show more code, provide `Bard` class code, and show us how you imported.

Comment: You must have imported Bard (being the file containing some class definitions)? That does not entitle you to access an individual class from Bard using dot notation. Furthermore, even if you imported a class definition from Bard, you cannot access a method or sub-object of that class unless it is declared static and not therefore belonging to an instance object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* do what you're asking (through a combination of `globals()` and `getattr`), it's a bad idea to do so. Your variable names should not be data in your program. Variable names are for you the programmer to use, not for your users.

Instead, use a dictionary or some other data structure to map from one kind of data (e.g. a string like `'bard'`) to another kind of data (e.g. the `bard.Bard` class). Use that mapping to process the user input into the data you actually need to use.

Here's a very simplified example:

```
class Bard:
   spell_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']

class_name_mapping = {'bard': Bard, 'fighter': ...}

user_class_name = input('What class is your character? ')
user_class = class_name_mapping[user_class_name.lower()]
user_spell_list = user_class.spell_list
print(f'Your spells are: {", ".join(user_spell_list)}.')
```